# How can I prettify jades output with sails.js?

Tags: express, sails.js

I'm updating my sails.js 0.9 app to 0.10. With the old version I could prettify the output of jade this configuration:

```
module.exports.config = function () {
  if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {
    // Pretty print output
    sails.express.app.locals.pretty = true;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately this has changed and I don't know how. How can I prettify my html code with the new sails.js version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `config/express.js`

```
customMiddleware: function (app) {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
},
```

Check the node environment, if you only want to prettify in development stage:

```
customMiddleware: function(app) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.locals.pretty = true;
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added how I can check for the environment stage to your answer.